# How to get err and result when using await

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have a function that receives a callback as a parameter. For example:

```
client.sendMessage(params, (status, response) => {
  console.log('Status: ', status);
  console.log('API Response:\n', response);
});
```

I then promisify it:

```
const Promise                 = require('bluebird');
const sendMessageFunc: Object = Promise.promisify(client.sendMessage);
```

Then I call it:

```
result = await sendMessageFunc(params);
```

I actually want to get the `(status, response)` to then do:

```
(status, response) = await sendMessageFunc(params);
console.log('Status: ', status);
console.log('API Response:\n', response);
```

But that is not valid syntax. What should I do? What is the "result" object that is being returned to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of `await` is to flatten you asynchronous code to be like a synchronous code which would throw in a case of error (like `JSON.parse` for example) 
when awaiting on an asynchronous function - if the asynchronous function returned a result - it is returned as if the function was synchronous,
if the asynchronous function threw an exception - `await` re-throws it, as if the function was synchronous.

so, first of all, there is no "status", only exceptions. you should surround your `await` expression with `try`/`catch`:

```
try{
    let response = await sendMessageFunc(params);
    console.log('API Response:\n', response);
}
catch(e){
    console.error('an error was thrown: ' + e.toString());
}
```

the promise is just a convenient vehicle to implement a coroutine (which is what async/await keywords actually create). don't think in terms of promises when using `await`, it's just an implementation detail.